# YoloV8 optimization for smartphone

Tags: tensorflow.js, yolov8

I am using the model YoloV8 with tensorflow.js.
I am trying to make realtime image segmentation with cam.

I am using this example, which work good on computers but very slow on smartphone. And my need is to optimize it for smartphone.

[Object Segmentation Application Using YOLOv8 and Tensorflow.js](https://github.com/ezawadzki/yolov8-seg-tfjs)

Instead to detect 80 kind of object, maybe I could optimize it for 2 or 3 objects only.
For that, is there an option for that in tensorflow.js or do I need to train with a new dataset ?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to export your model to an android friendly framework such as TFLite. This will give you ~10FPS on a decent phone CPU for the `s` model. You can further increase the FPS by exporting to TFLite INT8. This will only give you boosts if the CPU/GPU supports INT8 operations.